# Showing a view controller in Modal Dialog programmatically is appearing as full screen

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I have 2 swift View controllers and i want the second one to show as a modal dialog ( like bootstrap modal in web) on top of the first view when i click a button. I used the below code to achieve this, but the second view controller is still appearing full screen!

This is the code i execute to show the second view controller

```
var addCtrl = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mCtrl") 
                             as? ModalContentViewController
addCtrl!.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
presentViewController(addCtrl!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

`mCtrl` is the storyboard id of the second viewcontroller.

What am i missing here ? My objective is to show the second view controller in a modal dialog.

EDIT : I am trying to make it work on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention whether you're on iPhone or iPad.  Assuming you're on iPad, if you want something like a modal dialog, then you'd be better off using `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`, which in swift I guess would be `.FormSheet`.  If you really want to use a popover, you'll need to tell it where to popover from.  You'd do this by setting the `sourceView` and `sourceRect`, or the `barButtonItem` properties of the controller's `popoverPresentationController`, *after* the call to `presentViewController`.

If you're on the iPhone, you'd still get a full screen presentation in both these cases.  However, you can get the iPad style presentations if you set the presenting controller to be the presented controller's `presentationController`'s delegate, *before* the call to `presentViewController`, and then implement `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:traitCollection` to always return `UIModalPresentationNone`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Apple's documentation, you try setting `preferredContentSize` explicitly for the popover view. Something like 
`addCtrl!.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 100)`

> The value in this property is used primarily when displaying the view controller’s content in a popover but may also be used in other situations. Changing the value of this property while the view controller is being displayed in a popover animates the size change; however, the change is not animated if you specify a width or height of 0.0.